# Spree access children of taxon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a Rails Spree app. I need to get list of children taxons of "Categories".

Categories is the name of a taxon that has "Men" and "Women" under it.

On development I am able to do this with this code:

```
<% @taxons = Spree::Taxonomy.find_by_name("Categories").taxons[0].children %>
```

However this is not working in Production. There is a taxon with this name on Production as well and it has children.

Any pointers? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can improve readability of this code to

   `Spree::Taxonomy.find_by(name: 'Categories').taxons.first.children`

But usually first taxon of taxonomy has same name as taxonomy and it is taxonomy root. And you can use to be sure that you are looking for main taxonomy's taxon.

```
 Spree::Taxonomy.find_by(name: 'Categories').root.children
```

Also you can make scope in Taxon model.

2. 'Not working in production'
   Can you give what error do you have? Because you can have some issue with 'Categories' ex. 'categoriess' or sth like that. In my personal opinion better save all main hardcoded names in I18. Its easier to refactor later, make scopes etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
Spree::Taxonomy.find_by_name("Categories").taxons.find_by_name('Men').products
```